# DataGridView and CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I connected the database to DataGridView using dataset and I set the:

```
DataGridView.autogenerate=false
```

then I added column by column using gui properties, and then I made one of the columns as a checkbox.

First I would like to set the value of the check box to true or false and then check if the value is true, if true then I would like to get the value of another column but in the same row and then hide the current row.

Comment: I wonder what API you are using... Winform? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: I am using c# windows forum application

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need to check if that cell is checked.

```
if (DataGridViewRow.Cells[CellNumber].Value != null)
{
    if ((Boolean)DataGridViewRow.Cells[CellNumber].Value == true)
    {
        //Get other cell value
    }
}
```

Once you do that, you can hide the row.

```
DataGridViewRow.Visible = false;
```